# Unity3D Move step by step

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

I am trying to make my locomotion system in Unity that I will later use for Oculus.

Right now I created a object with camera and a rigidbody called "rb".

```
    // Perform movement
void PerformeMovement ()
{
    if (velocity != Vector3.zero) {
        rb.position = (rb.position + velocity);
    }
}
```

I calculate velocity in my other class.
I am trying to do 2 things..

1. Make the movement feel more like teleporting. Right now it's smoothly moving to a new position.
2. Make the rigidbody stop for a second or two after the step. So that holding down will not feel like running.

Any API hints? Not looking for someone to write it for me... Or mby links to similar locomotion systems?

Main Goal is to make the movement more incremented than smooth and so I could bypass conflicts that cause nausea.

EDIT!

Right now I updated my code to >

```
    void PerformeMovement ()
{
    if (velocity != Vector3.zero) {
        if (timer % 60 == 1 ) {
            rb.MovePosition (rb.position + velocity * 20);
        }
    }

}
```

It works kinda like I want but how can i deal with collisions now?
If the step is long enough it will just step through the object. If the step is too small it gets stuck and then randomly flies away...

Comment: For your #2, make a `private float lastMove;` then do a  `lastMove = Time.timeSinceLevelLoad;` when you do a move then check that `if(lastMove + pauseTime > Time.timeSinceLevelLoad)` before you allow the next move.

Comment: Timer is a random int that is incremented by 1 at every Update(). And my experience of C# is 2 days so I cant not quite get your suggestion.

Comment: Also, you are likely to get people more knowledgeable on how to make a good VR experience if you ask on the [Unity subform](https://forums.oculus.com/viewforum.php?f=37) on the Oculus site.

Comment: Thank you for that :D I somehow just forgot about Unity forum

Comment: If you get a good solution told to you there feel free to come back here and post an answer to your own question and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Let's call your game object "G1" and a duplicate of that game object "G2".

You would remove anything physics related from G1 and you would remove the renderer from G2. The idea is that G2 is some kind of physics ghost for G1. That is, G2 moves freely without your special rules of movement and thereby collisions are properly handled. You would then just update G1 transform to G2 transform occasionally to visually create your desired movements.

Comment: I have done this. I have a "G2" sphere that acts as a visual and a camera inside that acts as "G1"